# How can I get the value AND label on a radio button in knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My model holds both a numerical score (numerical value) for each radio option in a group,  and also a label (text) for each same radio option.

Think of a survey - the prompted responses to each question vary from question to question.

```
<td data-bind="foreach: allowed_responses"><input type="radio" data-bind="value: score, checked: $parent.selectedResponse" /><span data-bind="text: label"></span></td>
```

And then my javascript will give me the numerical value of the selected radio button.

```
self.getSelectedScores = function() {
....
"score": questions[i].selectedResponse()
....
```

How would I pickup the the label of the chosen radio button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `checkedValue` binding. It takes the entire object as the selected value instead of just the score.

```js
var viewModel = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.allowed_responses = ko.observableArray([
    {
      'score' : 1,
      'label' : 'One'
    },
    {
      'score' : 2, 
      'label': 'Two'
    }
  ]);
  
  self.selectedResponse = ko.observable();
  self.getSelectedScoreandLabel = function(){
    console.log('label: ' + self.selectedResponse().label);
    console.log('value: ' + self.selectedResponse().score);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko foreach: allowed_responses -->
<td>
  <input type="radio" data-bind="value: score, checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedResponse" />
  <span data-bind="text: label"></span>
</td>
<!-- /ko -->
<br>
<br>
<button data-bind="click: getSelectedScoreandLabel">Show response</button>
```

P.S. `foreach` doesn't seem to be working with `<td>`, so I used a virtual element.